# Android Emulator - How to emulate headset plugging action

Tags: android, emulation, headset

Android Emulator - How to emulated headset plugged.

1. Is it possible to simulate the action of a headset being plugged in?
2. Basically, I want this intent fired - `Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`. Is there any other way to do this other than simulating a headset being plugged in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [official reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html) on Android emulator:
*Emulator Limitations:

In this release, the limitations of the emulator include:*

- No support for device-attached headphones

Perhaps you could test it with mock objects and events? (JUnit?)

Comment: Is it still not possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to turn on the headset then you could try this:

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)
manager.setBluetoothScoOn(boolean on);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Lesser AudioSwitch app. It will let you switch input (and output) devices manually. [Here is the quick instruction on how to use it](https://ivanderevianko.com/2021/02/fix-smule-headphones-are-required-to-save-your-collab-on-android-emulator)

This program tricked Smule that I was running on emulator. Smule requires headset to record audio, and no other methods worked to trick Android, except Lesser AudioSwitch